# Why do some Windows executables have the compatibility tab disabled (others don't)?

Tags: windows-10, compatibility, visual-studio-2013

I'm running Windows 10 Enterprise. I downloaded a program directly from Microsoft. It's an installer for Visual Studio 2013. I have to support older installations so that's the main reason why I did this.

When I try to run it, the installer complains about "Blocked by another condition on your computer". I went down the rabbit hole of searching for reasons/workarounds/reading log files etc and now I've come to the realization that Microsoft does not want me to install this.

When I right-click on the .exe and choose Properties, I do not get a "compatibility" tab. However, other executables do have the tab.

So basically the question is: Is there another rabbit hole for me to explore such that I can enable the compatibility tab?

I understand from the Microsoft website that VS2013 is not supported on Windows 10. However, several of my colleagues have Windows 10 and somehow they were able to install it but this was a year or two ago.

Comment: This sounds like a signed executable issue and/or a group policy configuration.    However, I suspect, "Blocked by another condition on your computer" is not an accurate English translation of the error message.  Is the error message exactly that or are you attempting to translate it?  It sounds like a group policy error based on the context.  I had no problem installing Visual Studio 2013 on my Windows 10 machine by the way.

Comment: It could simply be that Smart Filter is active and somehow classified the file as unsafe. You can find a setting in the general tab to trust the file regardless and that should bring the compatibility tab back if you reopen the properties page.

Comment: Well, I have found the workaround...

Comment: I have found the workaround... By the way, "Blocked by another condition on your computer" is the message (as best as I could copy) of the VS2013 installer itself. Anyway, after interrogating my colleagues, I found out they had installed VS2013 on their Windows 10 machines using an old DVD. So I was able to install VS2013 this way. Now, for the interesting bit, I tried to run the original and problematic MS VS2103 web installer again and LO AND BEHOLD-> It runs now! The exe file still does not have the "compatibility" tab in the properties window but at least I can update VS2013 to update 5.

Comment: For the sake of completeness this is the history: 1) Buy brand-new computer from our vendor. 2) IT group puts "approved" Windows 10 with all the patches they deem necessary for inclusion into our corporate network. 3) I go to MSDN site and download VS2017 Professional so I can do some work. 4) Weeks go by. 5) I suddenly become aware that I absolutely need to get VS2013 on my machine (don't get me started, I'm a Linux penguin) for legacy reasons. I go to MSDN and download VS2103. 6) The installer won't run. 7) I spend hours chasing rabbits. 8) Found workaround (see above). Thanks for reading.

Comment: One of my projects still uses VS2013 and I can install that old version on Windows 10 without problem. Probably some group policy prevents you from executing such files